# Using Azure SQL Services from a Mac?

Tags: macos, odbc, azure, azure-sql-database, unixodbc

Azure SQL Services looks pretty cool, and I'd like to use it as a hosted database. I set myself up with a starter web edition database, and after clicking through a million and five EULAs, I got to a console and created a database. It gave me a connection string for ODBC, and for ADO.NET.

I'm using a Mac, with 10.6. What are my options?

Ideally, I'd find something like Sequel Pro or Querious that works with ODBC. Failing that, is there a web console or something?

I suppose there's always DBI::Shell in perl.

Is there anything better than installing Windows 7/VS2010 in VMWare?

Answer (score 9):

You may like [SQLPro for MSSQL](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sql-client-database-management/id828466809?mt=12) ([mac app store](http://www.macsqlclient.com/)).

The app has a few neat features such as:

- Auto-completion and syntax highlighting.
- Azure database support (also supports federation).
- Tabbed based interface.
- Support for executing multiple queries at once.
- Quick access to tables, columns and more.
- Stored procedure execution.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of this app. I built it because I wanted a tool for accessing MSSQL databases without running a windows virtual machine. I use this tool on a daily basis now and am continually adding updates and new features to it.

Comment: Which ODBC driver is used by SQLPro ?

Comment: SQLPro uses FreeTDS.

Comment: Can you use FreeTds without having SQLPro under GPL license?

Comment: FreeTDS is LGPL, which to my understanding can be used in commercial products as long as the proper terms are followed. There are many larger discussions about this (see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/47323/can-i-use-an-lgpl-licenced-library-in-my-commercial-app for an example).

Answer (score 5):

Use [Visual Studio Code with mssql extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-vscode) to connect and query data on Azure SQL database.

Comment: Actually it is one of the best free options to query MS SQL from Mac OS X. Installed seamlessly and working perfect

Answer (score 2):

SQL Azure provides a standard TDS stream so any program which can connect to a local sql server could connect given the right connection string.  See http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-azure.  Also take a good hard look at if you even need a fully relational database.  If you dont, [Azure Table Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179423.aspx) might be a good answer.

Comment: Thanks, though I guess then my question is "is there a decent TDS client for the Mac?", short of DBI::Shell. 

I also assure you that I need a relational database :)

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452/sql-client-for-mac-os-x-that-works-with-ms-sql-server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm successfully using [OpenLink's SQL Server Lite Driver v6.0](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc/) to connect to SQL Azure through Mac OS X Lion.

Answer (score 1):

## Navicat Lite no longer exists

If you want something like Sequel Pro, I'd suggest [Navicat Lite](http://www.navicat.com/). It connects to my SQL Azure instances just fine, and the Lite version is free. It's a native OSX client, so there isn't any funky UI going on. The Lite version excludes some things like visual query building, but overall is very useful.

Comment: Is it just me or does Navicat Lite not exist anymore - just free trials of the various Navicat products? http://www.navicat.com/download

Answer (score 1):

@Erik Paulson, check out [SQL-CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-cli), its a great command line tool to connect to Azure SQL Database and SQL Server natively on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

[DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) from JetBrains (makers of IntelliJ and PyCharm) is also a great option to query Azure SQL Database from a Mac.

[image]

Comment: Note:  I had to do this on Mac OS 10 Sierra to get DataGrip to connect (via JDBC):
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JRE-221#comment=27-1826316

Answer (score 0):

If you want a free option, and just need a commandline interface, you can install freetds. I found a great page on it here, it got me in and running without spending money.

https://martinrichards.tumblr.com/post/28488121620/connecting-to-sql-azure-using-freetds

I would note however, remeber you need to whitelist your PUBLIC IP on the Azure Console SQL server firewall (what you get when you google "what is my IP"). Remember that Azure is sitting out in the cloud, so you need to whitelist the IP it sees

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest you look at using [oData](http://www.odata.org/blog/got-sql-azure-then-youve-got-odata).

It's a RESTful protocol, and there is already an official objective-C SDK:
http://www.odata.org/developers/odata-sdk