# sql server client for mac

Tags: sql-server, macos

I'm looking for a  SQL Server client that will run on Mac OS X. Ideally, I'd like something lightweight that allows me to easily browse the schema, run adhoc queries, highlight SQL syntax, etc.

I really like SQL Yog, so something like that would be perfect, any recommendations?

Comment: MS Access, if it's available in Office for Mac, can do most of that, other than the syntax highlighting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Client for Mac OS X that works with MS SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452/sql-client-for-mac-os-x-that-works-with-ms-sql-server)

Comment: This is off topic, as it's asking for an off-site resource (software).

Answer (score 1):

You may like [SQLPro for MSSQL](http://macsqlclient.com) ([App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/sqlpro-for-mssql-database/id828466809?mt=12)).

The app has a few neat features such as:

- Syntax highlighting.
- Intellisense.
- Tabbed based interface.
- Support for executing multiple queries at once.
- Quick access to tables, columns and more.
- Query primary key detection and the ability to edit/delete/insert rows directory from query results.
- Support for MSSQL 2005+ database, including those hosted on Azure.
- NTLMv2 supported (but not required).
- Netbios hostnames supported.

There is a seven day trial available [via the website](http://macsqlclient.com). If you purchase via our [website](http://macsqlclient.com), use the promo code **STACK25** to save 25%.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you [NAVICAT](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_sqlserver/sqlserver_detail_mac.html). It's not free but it's not **that** expensive either. Other than that, any JDBC based solution would work, although they might not be as lightweight as you may want. [SQuirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Aqua Data Studio](http://www.aquafold.com/)?  It's not very lightweight but if the database is small it should handle it easily.

Answer (score 0):

DBVisualizer.  Been around for a while.  Not the cheapest but has a lot of bell/whistles and works very consistently bet/ MAC and Windows.

Supports all commercial/popular DBs.

http://www.dbvis.com/

Answer (score 0):

You may like [Valentina Studio](http://valentina-db.com/en/valentina-studio-overview), which is FREE for its 80% of features. Some advanced features go as Pro Edition.

The app has a few neat features such as:

- Syntax highlighting.
- Intellisense.
- Tabbed based interface.
- Support for executing multiple queries at once.
- Quick access to tables, columns and more.
- Support for MSSQL 2005+ database, including those hosted on Azure.
- Have powerful Report Tools
- Query Builder
- Schema Editor
- Diagram Editor, forward and reverse engineering
- Data Editor with unique Related Tables feature
- SQL Diff
- Works in mac, win and Linux also. Natively. C++ app.
- etc and etc

Disclaimer: I'm from Paradigma Software.