# Connecting to sql server from mac

Tags: sql-server, macos

I want to access sql server from my mac book. Is there any alternative for MS SQL server management studio available for mac?

I could not find answers in the web search also.  I am wondering how people could always access SQL server from windows machine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452/sql-client-for-mac-os-x-that-works-with-ms-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Use Oracle's [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html). As strange as it sounds, an Oracle product allows you to [connect to a Microsoft database](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/sql-server-connection-viewlet-swf-089886.html).