# Sql Developer connector to Sql Server 2012 - error "Vendor code 207"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, oracle-sqldeveloper, jtds

I am trying to connect from Sql Develper 4.0.3.16 to Sql Server 2012, with jTDS connector jtds-1.3.1.jar.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Java:

```
~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)
```

In the create connection window, when I test the connection it is successful.

When I open the connection I can see all the databases. When I try to open a database that I am supposed to have a permission to open, I am getting the following error window:

[image]

Any ideas?

P.S. if Microsoft has a [JDBC driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774) `sqljdbc4-4.0.jar` (which works for me when I connect from Java code to Sql Server 2012), then why do I have to use jTDS in order to connect Sql developer to Sql Server? It seems like the Microsoft jdbc driver is not accepted by Sql Developer when I try to used it as a connector.

**Before clicking on `+`**

[image]

**After clicking on `+`**

[image]

Comment: To open a table? You mean performing a SELECT query? From the error message I think you're trying to retrieve data from a table that doesn't have the column 'suid'..

Comment: To expand a table by clicking on the `+` on its left side.

Comment: 1. seems that you are trying to retrieve data about the column which does not exist in the specified table or 2. table name is not correct or 3. you are trying to access a view (not table) and the view does not hold any column like suid or 4. you need to re-phrase your question

Comment: @Shantanu I just attached screenshots and made a few corrections to my wording.

Comment: It s**ks not being able to retrieve the list of tables. While Oracle fixes it, I'm using the following query to do it, hope it helps: use some_database; select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_type='BASE TABLE';

Answer (score 5):

As it's explained [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3698597?start=0&tstart=0), so far sql developer supports only up to sql server 2012. In my case I'm using 2014 version, which isn't supported.

**UPDATE**
There've been several updates, which provide support to newer databases. Check them out, now I'm able to connect to my servers using SQL Developer.

Comment: it would have been nice if it was mentioned where are those updates might be.

Comment: Sorry for not posting it. Latest version is 17.4.0.355.2349

Answer (score 1):

Download latest version of Oracle SQL developer which works flawlessly to connect SQL server. Make sure you export all your connections before being downloaded the newer version which is 19.2, etc.