# Client for SQL Database (DB2) service at Bluemix

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

Any recommendation for an OS X client to connect with the SQL Database at Bluemix (DB2).

Thank you in advance

/Eduardo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find some info at:
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SQLDB/index.html#connecting-to-sqldb
and
[SQL Client for Mac OS X that works with MS SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452/sql-client-for-mac-os-x-that-works-with-ms-sql-server)